# could anyone suggest me 2 solve this?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relationship, sql-insert

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dihr`.`tbl_contract`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_contract_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `tbl_attactment` (`contract_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

INSERT INTO `tbl_contract` (`staff_id`, `type_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `status`) VALUES ('2', '1', '2018-03-20', '2018-03-30', '1')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

[This is relationship table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM2aS.png)

[This is error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeiiS.png)

Comment: you are not inserting `id`

Comment: id - >  is auto_increment

Comment: No. According to relationship diagram,it's a foreign key that refers to `contract_id` from `tbl_attactment` it should other way around in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

The `id` column in the table `tbl_contract` is dependent on the `contract_id` column in table `tbl_attactment`

1. You are not inserting this `tbl_contract.id` column in your insert.
2. If you do, you should be aware that the `tbl_contract.id` should exist in the `tbl_attactment.contract_id`